# Testing a random generator using QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I've written a random generator to create a minesweeper board. It returns a Gen Board, where Board is my own defined datatype. I want to test that it does what it's supposed to. As it is a generator, I can't use the functions I'm used to which returns a Bool or Property. Is there a good way to test generators using quickCheck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have

```
genBoard :: Gen Board
isValidBoard :: Board -> Bool
```

You can test that the generator is valid with the `forAll` combinator,

```
prop_genBoardMakesValidBoards :: Property
prop_genBoardMakesValidBoards = forAll genBoard isValidBoard
```

It is harder to test that the generator is random enough, for example that it doesn't always return a trivial board.

Comment: Nice! Although my generator takes paremeter to decide size, number of mines etc. I guess you could pass them to prop_genBoardMakesValidBoard and pass them on to the genBoard function?

Comment: A function of type `Int -> Proprety` is also testable, so you can pass it to `quickcheck` and the like. It will generate random numbers to give to your function.